# How to use angular $http to send FormData

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append('type', type);
formData.append('description', description);
formData.append('photo', photo);  

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('POST', '{{ path('my_webservice') }}');
request.send(formData);
```

How can I send my `FormData` using `$http`?

My main problem with the above code is that I don't know how to generate a callback when the response is received.

So, if I can do it in Angular I'm in more familiar territory.

Thanks

### Edit

This seems to work asynchonously. Seems better than any of the Angular solutions suggested in terms of ease of implementation.

```
                request.onload = function (e) {
                    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                        console.log(request.responseText);
                    }
                };
```

Comment: I would suggest reading up on angular.  Check out $resource and $http.

Comment: I know how to use `$http`, but I'm not sure what to do with `formData`. Every time I've used `$http` in the past I have a JSON object I can pass - in this case I have a `formData`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$http` to post.

But the `content-type` has to be changed to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and the data should be serialized using `key=value` pairs.

These settings should be injected to underlying `XMLHttpRequest` object of the `$http`.

[Here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2615-posting-form-data-with-http-in-angularjs.htm) is an article which shows you how to do that.

Comment: It says `This does not use the "multipart/form-data" content type, which is primarily used for form posts that include binary file uploads.`. And `photo` in my initial example is a pointer to a file upload. Will this be a problem for me?

Comment: Please experiment with the content-type and see what works for you. I showed you the broad way of how you can use angular to submit form data in conventional format.

Comment: Line 51 of the example you link to - the data is a JSON object. How can I include my photo in that given it is a pointer to a file?

Comment: You should use FileReader API to read your local file in to a variable and include it in the form data in a suitable format. Here is your reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Comment: Due to the nature of the app I'm making, I've had to create a directive such that when the change event of a file input is called I store a pointer to that file in the JSON object (so I can send the Form Data as demonstrated in the first message).

Comment: Use the FileReader at that point and read the file data directly instead of the file name.

Comment: At what point? When I append the photo to the `formData`?

Comment: When the user selects the file. Actually that is the point you can use FileReader.

Comment: I've edited the original message with the solution I am using now. I think the Javascript approach seems like a more logical solution in this case.

Comment: I answered your original question about using $http for FormData

Answer (score 0):

Add an `ng-submit` attribute to your form and assign it a function to handle the POST request using the $http service. Angular handles http responses using the `promises` API. Here is an example from https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl',
  data: { type: 'myType',
          description:'myDescription'
 }
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Comment: This will encode his form data in json.

Comment: @downvoter, What did I miss?

Comment: What's wrong with JSON? How would you do encode data in Javascript?

Comment: This solution doesn't even contain my `formData` object. How do I post that?

Comment: You cannot expect a conventional form data phrase to decode data sent through this method. That's what is wrong with it.

Comment: Also the question is not about a DOM form which you can include ng-submit to.

Comment: Added data to the request body. Maybe @CharlieH can provide a better solution :)

Comment: Please see my answer for the exact (not only better) solution. Your answer is about the general use of $http. The question is about sending form data with $http.

Comment: @Price that still doesn't include the photo (pointer to a file upload) though.

Comment: Play with the content-type. Do your experiments and find the parameters you should use. I showed you how you should use angular in posting conventional form data.

Comment: @b85411, for uploading files, url-encoding of parameters won't work. You would have to use a FormData object and append your files, string data to it. Check this article that explains how to make such a request: http://www.angulartutorial.net/2015/03/file-upload-and-sending-data-to-backend.html

Answer (score 0):

**AngularJS**:

```
$http.post(myRestUrl, {my:"object"}).success(function(data, status, headers, config){/* DO STUFF*/});
```

Read more at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Or to do it with **XMLHttpRequest**:

```
client.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(this.readyState == 2) {
    print(this.getAllResponseHeaders());
  }
}
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-send%28%29-method

Comment: This answer doesn't show how to send form data using it's original headers and serialization.

Comment: what are you talking about?